# VisualStudio XAML designer preview differs from actual Windows Phone app view

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone, blend

Take a look at the photo, Visual Studio 2013 (as well as Blend) designer shows different rendering than on actual Windows Phone 8.1 device (Lumia 930):

[image]
[image]

Look at the red backgrounds widths: designer shows it like **left** aligned, but device renders as **stretch**.

The questions are: why and what causes this problem and how to fix it or workaround?

[Sample project](https://github.com/inTagger/Bugs/tree/master/WinPhoneAlignment).

Gist:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <SampleData:SampleDataSource x:Key="SampleDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TestItemTemplate">
    <Border Background="#FFA20F00">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
    </Border>
  </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}">
  <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}"/>
</Grid>
```

Found workaround:

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter"/>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

It seems to be a bug in the VisualStudio. [Here's the MS Connect bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1199238).

Comment: Uhm, okay. Neat. What is your question?

Comment: Instead of stating "this doesn't work", can you provide us information on how you expect the view to look, and show the XAML you have currently. An image of a screen doesn't help in that regard. We can't read your mind, so it's difficult to guess what kind of answer you want, and what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @Patrick, I though it is obviously that gray background alignment differs and it is obviously very weird. Anyway, I have updated the question.

Comment: Of course it's weird, but something being weird is not a question. I'm not certain that it would help, but could you post the XAML you are using, in case someone would want to verify this themselves, and perhaps figure out a solution?

Comment: @Patrick done. Added new screenshots and code example and link on the github repo.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for direction, this style helped: ```<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter"/>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>``` Can you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that Visual Studio just has a different template than what is actually on the device for some reason. Try setting the alignment of the itemcontainer manually by adding an ItemContainerStyle to your ItemsControl.

Depending on what you want to do, change the value of the setter. Set it to left to mimic the behavior in Visual Studio, or Stretch to make it look like it is on the device.

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestItemTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding TestCollection}">

  <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
  </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

</ItemsControl>
```